# How to programmatically change scope selected in searchbar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller, uisearchbardelegate

I want to change the selected scope after user has selected something from a table view. 
I have tried this:

```
for (id view in [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar subviews]) {
    if ([view isMemberOfClass:[UISegmentedControl class]])
        {
            UISegmentedControl *scopeBar = view;
            scopeBar.selectedSegmentIndex = 1;
        }
}
```

But the scope button i want is still not selected. My search bar doesn't have a subview of class UISegmentedControl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you mean the scopes of an `UISearchBar` and you already have your `UISearchBar` set up so it shows scopes.

The UISearchBar has a special property that needs to be set:

```
self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The way it worked for me was with [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar setSelectedScopeButtonIndex:1];

Comment: Strange, both ways mean the same thing at the end. Anyway, glad I could help :-)